# Obter valor de radio button via jQuery e chamar um codigo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, gostaria de receber uma ajuda, sou iniciante na área de programação. Preciso saber como faço para que o que estiver selecionado o radio ele chame um determinado código.

```
<form method="POST" action="questoes.php">
    <label>Tipo da questão:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="dissertativa"> Dissertativa <br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="objetiva"> Objetiva <br><br>

    <input type="button" name="pergunta" id="pergunta" value="pergunta">
</form>
```

Comment: E que código seria esse? uma função? esse código corre numa página HTML? Já testaste `oninput="minhaFuncao()"`?

Comment: não está claro, vc quer fazer um `if` para executar um código de acordo com o valor do radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas se quando você diz chama um outro código é redirecionar a página você pode utilizar href. 
HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="questoes.php">
 <label>Tipo da questão:</label><br>
<input id="dissertativa" type="radio" name="tipo" value="dissertativa"> Dissertativa <br>
<input id="objetiva" type="radio" name="tipo" value="objetiva"> Objetiva <br><br>

<input type="button" name="pergunta" id="pergunta" value="pergunta">
        </form>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ //eu acrescentei o id nos inputs
            $("#dissertativa").click(function(){
              window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com"
            })
        });
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#objetiva").click(function(){
              window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com"
            })
        });
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#pergunta").click(function(){
              window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com"
            })
        });
```